# Can I use my own custom component for Supabase auth-helpers?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, supabase-database

I can't get the [Auth component](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs) provided by `@supabase/auth-ui-react` to match my design and I'd also like to add additional inputs. Can I use my own Auth component and still use `@supabase/auth-helpers-react` auth system that comes with SessionContextProvider etc..?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, do this in your login page

```
import { useSupabaseClient} from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
const supabase = useSupabaseClient()
let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({email:'email here',password:'password here'})
```

Comment: What does this code do and how does it work?

Comment: this code is for nextJs since it comes with some helpers '@supabase/auth-helpers-react' you don't instantiate supabase client somewhere in your app and export it and use it anywhere, nextJs helpers give you access this way, and the last line of that code is for the Login logic. BUT if you are using ReactJs, you just use the supabase client that you export normally, and on Login button use the last line of code above, but your supabase client will not come from the helper package that supabase gives to NextJs devs.